# C++ automatic implicit conversion from const char to string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

Ok so Im just learning templates for the first time and so I was toying around creating my own  template class that mimics its underlying type which is a vector. Keep in mind that the call to push_back just calls the push_back method of the underlying vector.

```
vector<string> sV;
sV.push_back("ha");       //ok: converts from const char[3] to string

Foo<string> fS;
fS.push_back("ha");      //error: const char[3] does not match the argument list
```

Is there a way I can fix this? I just want my template to feel as natural as if I'm using the real thing.

---

**EDIT : This is basically the body of the class**

```
template <typename T> class FooPtr;
template <typename T>
class Foo{
    friend class FooPtr<T>;
public:
    Foo() {data->make_shared(vector<T>); }
#ifdef INITIALIZER_LIST
    Foo(initializer_list<T>);
#endif
    void push_back(T &t) { data->push_back(t); }
    void push_back(T &&t) { data->push_back(move(t)); }
    bool empty() { if (data->size() == 0) return true; }
    FooPtr<T> insert(size_t, T&);
    T& operator[](size_t);
    T& front();
    T& back();
    FooPtr<T> begin() { return FooPtr<T>(*this); }
    FooPtr<T> end() { return FooPtr<T>(*this, data->size()); }
    void pop_back() { data->pop_back(); }
    void pop_front() { data->pop_front; }
private:
    void check(const string&, size_t = 0);
    shared_ptr<vector<T>> data;
};
```

Comment: template <typename T> void Foo<&T>::push_back(T)
template <typename T> void Foo<&&T>::push_back(move(T))
Does that answer?

Comment: @RudolphRedNose, That shouldn't compile in the first place.

Comment: Jsut for  push_back(), please...

Comment: Unrelated (sorta): unless I'm not reading this right (a distinct possibility), that `std::move(t)` should be a `std::forward<T>(t)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig don't you think the answers are wrong here? shouldn't `void push_back(T &&t) ` be picked for his call? since during overload resolution the converting constructor of the std::string is called and the std::string hence formed is an rvalue?

Comment: @RudolphRedNose which compiler and which version of it are you using?

Comment: @Koushik You're correct; it should be invoking the rvalue-reference method regardless. [See it live](http://ideone.com/4h2db4). Makes me wonder what toolchain the OP is using.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think its a complier bug? maybe i'l post it as an answer so that no one get misguided.

Comment: @Koushik hard saying what it is. If anything the non-const reference parameter version `(T& t)`would make the choice even more blatant. I can see the calling code puking passing a `const std::string var = "data";` with the existing setup, but those literals should be creating a temp consumable by the rvalue-reference method. Odd.

Answer (score 6):

A method that should be able to accept a string literal same way as a std::string object must have a signature

```
void foo( const std::string & arg )
```

Therefore, your Foo::push_back must be

```
void Foo::push_back( const T & arg )
```

Comment: so simple... yet so brilliant.

Comment: @RudolphRedNose The Standard Library documentation is a rich hoard of information.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ the std::vector offers two methods for push_back which are overloaded.

One for const types and for non const types.

Your first push_back succeeds as the std::vector provides a function which can handle types like

```
 const char *
```

where const is the magic word. Your wrapper template just offers a push_back method with the signature

```
T & t
```

Extending your implementation with the following should solve your problem:

```
void push_back (const T& t) {data->push_back(t);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to only try to convert `const char*` (NOT `const char` or `char` or another type of `char`) to `string`, otherwise you're trying to map an  element to a STL-container/array of that element which is nonsense in C++.

Comment: Very cryptic, please explain and use standard English.

Comment: Yes,thanks, very much so. But I think OP's original problem was the missing const. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think your compiler is wrong. my reasoning is as follows

when you instantiate `Foo` with `std::string` the push_back member functions that are generated will be as follows

```
void push_back(std::string &t) { data->push_back(t); }           --1
void push_back(std::string &&t) { data->push_back(move(t)); }    --2
```

**1** will be picked if the argument is a non-const lvalue expression of type std::string.
**2** will be picked if the argument is a non-const rvalue expression of type std::string.

when you pass `"ha"` , user defined conversion in `std::string` kicks in and since the produced `std::string (std::string("ha"))` is an rvalue, **2** should be picked. even addition of const to **1** will not cause the **2** from not being picked.

a nice post from [STL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)